# what causes XPC error Connection interrupted

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsurlsession

I have piece of code that fires couple of requests using NSURLsession and sometimes I get the below message on debugger of xcode

> received XPC error Connection interrupted for message type 3
>   kCFNetworkAgentXPCMessageTypePACQuery

I am thinking what causes this issue ?

Is it something to be worried about ?

Googling doesn't help much

Comment: I have the same use case and the same error. Maybe it is related to firing concurrent requests on URLSession

Comment: I finished the url sessions and are in a tableview screen with connection to REALM. App is in rest, no user interaction done, still this error message pops up in the debug screen followed by the same message but 'interrupted' has been replaced by 'invalid'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is caused by Network Proxy like VPN/VPS ,close them and Command R again.

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same error.

During the first attempt I had the VPN on. After turning it off the message did not appear.